# select records which will be ended after 2 days

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I need to get the records that will be ended after two days
but always I got an empty datagridview.

I have tried this code:

```
    Dim after2days As Date = Today.Date.AddDays(3)
    Dim sqlstr As String = "SELECT * FROM tblvac where vend between " & Today.Date & "  and " & after2days & " "
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstr, Conn)
    ds.Reset()
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstr, Conn)
    da.Fill(ds)
    dgv.DataSource = ds
    Conn.Close()
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please ensure that you describe your situation correctly; I (incorrectly) submitted an edit changing tags. You need to say what you're doing (i.e. using VB.NET with a Microsoft Access database as a backend).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access SQL includes functions, `Date()` and `DateAdd()`, which can give you the date range you want for your query.

```
Dim sqlstr As String = "SELECT * FROM tblvac where vend between Date() and DateAdd('d', 3, Date());"
```

If you prefer to pass date values from your VB.Net code to the db engine, use a parameter query so that you needn't bother about date format and delimiters.  Just supply valid Date/Time values for the parameters.

Comment: There are more that one way to code... I admit your way removes the need to create after2days but I fail to see why a downvote.

Comment: I apologies... not sure what went on... just got down vote and then two more and now they have disappeared.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the downvote on your answer after I submitted mine.  So not really surprised that you suspected me.  But I think it's a mistake to speculate about who cast an anonymous downvote or the reason for the vote.

Comment: Agreed... +1 for your answer as its neet

Answer (score 2):

You are building your query as a string and thus need to use the convert to date function... for MS Access its DateValue see http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datevalue.php

Try

```
    Dim sqlstr As String = "SELECT * FROM tblvac where vend between 
DateValue('" & Today.Date & "') and DateValue('" & after2days & "') "
```

As commented by HansUp... this solution needs to have the date format as mm/dd/yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: No problems... It something that used to get me... you go to the effort of creating a date and you think is should work but you forget that the actual query is pass as a string.

Comment: I think you'll need to include some quotes ... the db engine throws an error (*"Data type mismatch ..."*) with `DateValue(2016-5-31)`, but it works with quotes: `DateValue('2016-5-31')`  And beware of date format.  *dmy* can be troublesome.  *mdy* will work.  *ymd* avoids any possible confusion about which number is the day and which is the month.

Comment: I'm confused... is OP using Microsoft Access (VBA) or VB.NET?

Comment: Going by the tags VB.net with MS Access

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now; OP appears to be using VB.NET with a MS Access DB as the backend DB.